# What does port attribute in target element mean in libvirt's serial port xml?

Tags: centos, qemu, kvm, libvirt, hypervisor

```
<devices>
  <!-- Serial port -->
  <serial type='pty'>
    <source path='/dev/pts/3'/>
    <target port='0'/>
  </serial>
</devices>
```

i have attached serial ports to my KVM instance using above XML element. what does port="0" represents here. how it will affect if change it . i tried changing it to 1,8086,.... but haven't found any change. can someone please explain about this port number.

Answer (score 0):

Its tty port.

means ttys0

If you enter an invalid number it might be reverting to default 0

Comment: I have tried to use 0,1,2,3 for four serial ports but it is not being assigned to respective file. i.e the port the serial port with port attribute 0 is not being assigned to ttyS0 of guest. and when i am giving something like 8086 it is not being reverted back to 0.